# Who wrote a book about a libertarian moon colony?

Tags: story-identification, moon

I read a sci-fi book once about a libertarian colony on the moon. They rebelled against earth, I think. What is the name or title?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A likely book that fits this description, is **The Moon is a Harsh Mistress** by
Robert Heinlein, 1966.   There are multiple  memorable parts, including the
aphorisms "it's no more free than the air you breathe" and "TANSTAAFL".

As for the rebellion, it turns out that rock throwing from the top of a gravity
well is... effective.